# Shadowing PersistentHashMap's 'get' function

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to come up with a data structure for exploring data that have been been marked with key terms, like "systems theory" or "Internet", using some set and lattice theory concepts I like. I thought maybe I could extend the way that hash maps work. I wrote some tests for the behavior I want, and then I realized I don't really understand how to work, or to do work, with types and protocols.

Here's the idea. I want to index a collection of data by sets of strings. E.g.,

```
(def data { #{"systems theory" "internet"} [1 2 3]
  #{"systems theory" "biology"} [4 5]
  #{"systems theory"} [6 7 8] })
```

For free, I get

```
(data #{"systems theory"})
;=> [6 7 8]
```

which is good.

But it would also be slick to be able to do something like

```
(data "biology")
;=> { #{"systems theory"} [4 5] }
```

When I thought of this I figured it wouldn't be difficult to tell the `get` method of PersistentHashMap to act as normal, unless its being asked to use a String as a key, in which case, do whatever is necessary to get the new data structure. But when it came to write code I just had a mess and I don't actually know how to design this thing.

I have my copy of Fogus's *The Joy of Clojure* and I'm going to read about types and protocols and extend-type and such and see if I can make sense of how and where built-in functions are defined and changed. But I would also love a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not create a new specialized map implementation but create a simple index map from the original data:

```
(def data {#{"systems theory" "internet"} [1 2 3]
           #{"systems theory" "biology"} [4 5]
           #{"systems theory"} [6 7 8] })

(def cats (->> data
               (map (fn [[cats val]]
                      (->> cats
                           (map (juxt identity #(hash-map (disj cats %) val)))
                           (into {}))))
               (apply merge)))

(get cats "internet")
;=> {#{"systems theory"} [1 2 3]}

(get cats "biology")
;=> {#{"systems theory"} [4 5]}

(get cats "systems theory")
;=> {#{"biology"} [4 5]}
```

You could also merge both of them if you want to:

```
(def full-index (merge data cats))

(get full-index "internet") ;=> {#{"systems theory"} [1 2 3]}
(get full-index #{"systems theory"}) ;=> [6 7 8]
```

If you still want to create the specialized map implementation, you might want to take a look into the following:

- [PersistenHashMap
  implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java)
- [sorted.clj](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/sorted.clj): "An
  implementation of Clojure's sorted collections written in Clojure".
  For instance, see [the code for
  PersistentTreeMap](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/sorted.clj/blob/master/src/sorted/core.clj#L72-L222)
  which is used to implement `sorted-map`
- [data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl): "Persistent sorted
  maps and sets with log-time rank queries"
- [data.priority-map](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/priority_map.clj):
  "A priority map is very similar to a sorted map, but whereas a sorted
  map produces a sequence of the entries sorted by key, a priority map
  produces the entries sorted by value.". Perhaps the code is easier to
  understand than the others.

It won't be easy if you want to keep the semantics of a hash-map (for example `count` should return the sum of the original map count plus the new keys count). You might want to use [collection-check](https://github.com/ztellman/collection-check) to test your implementation.

Comment: collection-check is a great suggestion. I am trying to be test-driven and this looks like a way to avoid losing functionality when making new data structures.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing may be possible, but I think you would be better off just writing a function to filter through your list for any sets containing your search terms.

Also, consider the access patterns you are going to be using, I suspect having the strings as keys and the document ids in a set may be more efficient and more flexible.

Comment: I think "This isn't the right approach" is the correct answer. I want to define functions around the concepts of "sets" and "elements" not "sets" and "java.lang.String" so fiddling about with `get` is logic at the wrong level of abstraction.